# Android webview recaptcha is not showing

Tags: android, webview

webclient

```
 private fun getInterceptedResponse(url: String): WebResourceResponse? {
        return try {
            val httpClient = OkHttpClient()
            val request: Request = Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .addHeader("X-header", BuildConfig.RESET_USERNAME_PASSWORD_HEADER)
                .addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .build()



 private val webClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    
            override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, url: String): WebResourceResponse? {
                return getInterceptedResponse(url);
            }
```

webview

```
webviewContent.apply {
                with(settings) {
                    javaScriptEnabled = true
                    domStorageEnabled = true;
                }

                webViewClient = webClient
                
                loadUrl(getWebUrl())
            }
```

Error

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to script at 'https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/4PnKmGB9wRHh1i04o7YUICeI/recaptcha__en.js' from origin 'https://my.site' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.", source: https://my.site (0)
```

is there a config in android to handle the cors policy?
or set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin